# How to restart loop with different variable in php/html

Tags: php, html

as you can see im doing a loop as below.
There are 2 data set involved:

```
$transaction_list_pending;
$transaction_list_completed;

    <?php
        foreach($transaction_list_pending as $transaction) {
    ?> 
        <div id="P<?php echo $transaction->trans_id; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered transaction-details" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    some content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

How do i restart this same loop by using `$transaction_list_completed` as the variable in the foreach statement?

Suggestion to copy the loop is not what im looking for (maybe if no other solution) as the html content for this Modal consists of hundreds of code line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [merge the arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
<?php
    foreach(array_merge($transaction_list_pending, $transaction_list_completed) as $transaction) {
?> 
    <!-- your HTML -->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply wrap it in another loop.

For example, this code:

```
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [4,5,6];
$c = [$a,$b];
foreach($c as $x) {
  foreach($x as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
  }
  echo "---<br>";
}
```

shows the following output:

```
1
2
3
---
4
5
6
---
```

Comment: yea.
but for me array merge already done the work.
and cleaner.

Comment: Sure. Just be careful with `array_merge`, because "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one." This solution doesn't suffer from that feature. But for usual arrays with numerical indexes, it is fine both ways.